# SQL - Multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

```
SELECT C.ClientID, C.ClientCode, C.FullName, E.FullName AS EmployeeName

FROM ClientID C, EmployeeInfo E, tmntClientTreatmentInfo T, CliniciansClients CC

JOIN CliniciansClients
ON CliniciansClients.ClientID = ClientID.ClientID
JOIN ClientID
ON ClientID.ClientID = CliniciansClients.ClientID
JOIN EmployeeInfo
ON EmployeeInfo.EmployeeID = CliniciansClients.EmployeeID
JOIN tmntClientTreatmentInfo
ON tmntClientTreatmentInfo.ClientID = ClientID.ClientID
```

The multi-part identifier "ClientID.ClientID" could not be bound. // Line 6

Comment: look up how to build a `select` statement.

Comment: downvoted for asking what i'm sure is a pretty basic sql related question? to someone with experience in this arena. i'm not much of a sql guru, only reason i asked. the query that i posted above does not necessarily fall in line with any of the "usually occurs when" articles that i have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony, there are lots of ways to do selects with joins and many different types of joins. But I would recommend you start by doing something basic, making sure it works, then if it's not performant or brings back duplicate data, start optimizing the joins or work on your normalization / denormalization. After a while, you'll get the hang of it. Until then, I quickly set up a postgres instance in Docker, created the tables you referenced, and this query should work:

```
SELECT C.ClientID, C.ClientCode, C.FullName, E.FullName AS EmployeeName

FROM ClientID C

JOIN CliniciansClients AS CC
ON CC.ClientID = C.ClientID
JOIN EmployeeInfo AS E
ON E.EmployeeID = CC.EmployeeID
JOIN tmntClientTreatmentInfo as leonardo
ON leonardo.ClientID = C.ClientID
```